# How to restart a Win32_Service remotely along with all of its dependencies

Tags: powershell, wmi, get-wmiobject

If i use the

```
$service.stopservice()
```

method i get an error because of the dependencies, What i need to do is to restart the service *and* all of its dependancies.

Similar to if using the GUI and i selected the top line service and pressed restart, first i would get a warning, then a list of other services that will be restarted too, which then goes through stopping each dependancy before restarting the top one and then restarting the dependancies.

I need to do this in powershell

```
Try {
    Write-host "Connecting to remote computer"
    $service = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $ip -Credential $cred -Filter "Name='$servname'"
    if ($service.Status -eq 'Running'){$ServiceStarted = $true}

    if($ServiceStarted -eq $true) {


    $StopResponse = $service.stopservice()  
    $StopReturnCode = Switch ($StopResponse.ReturnValue) {
    0{ "The request was accepted" }
    5{ "The service is already stopped" }
    10{ "The service failed to stop - run the script again" }
    default{ "Something unexpected happened" }
}
}
     Write-Host $StopReturnCode
} catch {
Write-Host "script noped out bro" :fore RED
}
```

The above works (albeit slowly) for a single service.

I've tried using -Force but this doesnt work and -Force -Confirm gives an error.

Comment: You can't use a switch on method calls. Use the `Restart-Service` cmdlet via `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: Are you saying i cant use the switch as its written there? because that script works fine, the switch is being used on the variable $StopResponse which is taking the return data from the method.

Comment: I'm saying you can't use the `-Force` switch with a method call (`$service.stopservice() -force`), which you had in your original question.

Comment: ahh ok, sorry thought you meant the switch used below, i removed the -force because its unhelpful as the code block is supposed to show a working method for the single service.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few thoughts on this use case.

You can get the dependencies a couple of ways... and start as needed, before your try and restart the one you are after.

```
# Review Dependent Services
Get-Service -Name Winmgmt -DependentServices
```

or

[Use Windows PowerShell to Display Service Dependencies](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-windows-powershell-to-display-service-dependencies)

```
Get-Service -CN $env:COMPUTERNAME | 
    Where-Object { $_.status -eq ‘running’} | 
    ForEach-Object { 
    write-host -ForegroundColor 9 "Service name $($_.name)" 
    if ($_.DependentServices) 
    {
        write-host -ForegroundColor 3 "tServices that depend on $($_.name)"
        foreach ($s in $_.DependentServices) 
        { "tt" + $s.name } 
    } #end if DependentServices 
    if ($_.RequiredServices) 
    {
        Write-host -ForegroundColor 10 "tServices required by $($_.name)"
        foreach ($r in $_.RequiredServices) 
        { "tt" + $r.name } 
    } #end if DependentServices 
} #end foreach-object
```

Addressing them can have different approaches, here is a discussion on the topic.

[How to restart services with dependencies via PowerShell Scripting (128574)](https://support.quest.com/appassure/kb/128574/how-to-restart-services-with-dependencies-via-powershell-scripting)

```
# For services with just a few dependencies, running 
Restart-Service winmgmt -Force -PassThru
```

> May suffice as all the currently running dependencies are restarted.
>
> However, this is an unsafe way do to the restart as some services may
>   have been previously stopped.
>
> For production machines, the following approach is recommended (the
>   example is using the WMI service):

```
cls
Write-Host "Restarting Service with Dependencies`r`n" -f Green

# 1. Get wmi dependencies
$wmidependents = (get-service winmgmt).dependentservices  

if desired to get only the running dependent services, pipe | where {$_.status -eq "running"}


# 2. Get all necessary information about dependent services
$wmidependentservices = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | 
Select-object name,state,startmode | 
Where-Object {$wmidependents.name -contains $_.name}

# 3. Stop wmi dependencies
Write-Host "`r`nStopping Services`r`n-----------------`r`n" -f Yellow


ForEach ($service in $wmidependentservices)
{
Write-Host "`r`nAnalyzing $($service.name)" -f Yellow

    if($service.startmode -eq "auto" -or $service.status -eq "Running")
    {
        Write-Host "Stopping $($service.name)"
        stop-service $service.name
        #you can add more logic in the block
    } 
    else
    {
        "$($service.name) is $($service.state) with the startmode: $($service.startmode)"
    }
}

#equivalent to stop-service $wmidependents.name

# 4. Stop the WMI service
Stop-Service winmgmt -force
Write-Host "`r`nStarting Services`r`n -----------------`r`n" -f Yellow

# 5. start dependencies

ForEach ($service in $wmidependentservices)
{
    Write-Host "`r`nAnalyzing $($service.name)" -f Yellow

    if($service.startmode -eq "auto")
    {
        "Starting $($service.name)"
        start-service $service.name
        #you can add more logic in the block
    } 
    else
    {
        "$($service.name) is $($service.state) with the startmode: $($service.startmode)"
    }
}

#equivalent to start-service $wmidependents.name

# 6. start WMI
Start-Service winmgmt
```

> Please note that both delayed-auto and auto startup types are shown as
>   "auto" by WMI.